# Ubuntu 17.10 cant change from xorg to wayland

Tags: xorg, 17.10, wayland

My login screen doesn't have the cog on it to switch. Please answer quickly as it really effects the speed at which i can emulate games at!

Comment: ive used echo $DESKTOP_SESSION to check if i am really on xorg and yes i am.

Comment: What video hardware is your system using?

Comment: amd a4 4300m apu with radeon hd 7420g, I used to be able to do it it just won't let me now.